# Unexpected behavior from String.Format()

Tags: c#, string

Given the following code, I would expect to an empty result or an exception:

```
String.Format(null, "Hello")
```

Instead, the result is the string "Hello". Why is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's working because it's choosing this overload:

```
public static String Format( IFormatProvider provider, String format, params Object[] args) { ... }
```

A `null` provider is OK, and no arguments to the varargs is also OK, and so it just prints out the string.

Intuitively, we might have expected this overload:

```
public static String Format(String format, Object arg0) { ... }
```

And of course, if it *did* choose that, we would have gotten an `ArgumentNullException`.

Answer (score 4):

It chooses overload

```
public static string Format(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args)
```

because your second argument has type of `string` (no conversion required). Thus this overload is closer, than overload with two parameters (it requires conversion from `string` to `object`):

```
public static string Format(string format, object arg0)
```

You can see the difference by calling:

```
String.Format(null, 5);
```

In this case conversion to object is chosen and you have an exception (actually there is no implicit conversion between `int` and `string`).

You can read more on choosing [best function member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on msdn.

Answer (score 2):

It might be interpreting the request as a call to the String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args) override and taking null as the provider and the params but "Hello" as the format, thus returning "Hello".

If you want an empty result use `String.Empty`